# yacc: e - unexpected end-of-file

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am writing a yacc input file.This is my code

```
%{
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "string.h"
    #include "exph.asc"
%}

%union {
    int value;
    struct symtab *symlink;
}

%token NAME
%token EXPR

%%

x
    : x dot
    | x p
    | x index
    | x b
    ;

b
    : '[' EXPR ']' b1 | Ɛ 
    ;

b1
    : '[' EXPR ']'
    Ɛ
    ;

dot
    : '.' NAME { $$= $2->value; $2->initialized = YES; }
    ;

index
    : '[' EXPR ':' EXPR ']'
    ;

p
    : '(' p
    | NAME p1 { $$= $1->value; }
    ;

p1 
    : ',' p
    | ')'
    | Ɛ
    ;

x
    : NAME { $$= $1->value; $1->initialized = YES; }
    ;

%%

struct symtab *symlook(char *str) {
    char *p;

    struct symtab *sp;

    for(sp = symtab; sp< &symtab[MAX_SYM]; sp++){
        if(sp->name && !strcmp(sp->name,str)) /* return pointer */
            return sp;

        if(!sp->name) { /* create new variable */
            sp->name = strdup(str);
            sp->initialized = NO;
            return sp;
        } 
    }
}

main()
{
    return(yyparse());
}

yyerror(s)
char *s;
{ 
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",s);
}

yywrap()
{
    return(1);
}
```

when I compile this code using yacc ,I get this error

yacc: e - line 1 of "expy.asc", unexpected end-of-file

can anyone help me where I am making mistake ?

Comment: looks like Ɛ needs some single quotes around it: 'Ɛ'. symlook should also always return a value

Comment: Hi Matthew Mcveigh I tried the code with Ɛ enclosed in single quote. But still having the same problem (unexpected end of file)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Berkeley yacc is utf-8 aware, so it's unlikely that using 'Ɛ' as a literal will work the way you might expect it to. But then, I'm not sure what you expect, exactly. It's even possible that you mean "empty production", but that is certainly not how you describe an empty production to yacc. When I tried it with Berkeley yacc v1.9 (`1.9 20121003`), I got an error message on line 25 complaining that Ɛ is an invalid character; quoting it did make that error go away.

The error message is the one produced if you provide an almost empty file to yacc. Is the file you pasted into the question actually called `expy.asc`? (yacc/bison input files are usually given a '.y' suffix, by the way. But you're free to ignore that convention).